# How to extract independent variable names from a formula with interaction and high order terms?

Tags: r, function

Suppose I have an R formula like this:

```
fm<-formula(y~x1*x2*x3+I(x4^2)*I(x5^2)
```

How could I extract the independent variable names like:

```
ind.fm<-c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the response variable and use `all.vars()`:

```
fm <- formula(y~x1*x2*x3+I(x4^2)*I(x5^2))
all.vars(fm[-2])
```

This may be answered elsewhere ...